# Converting SVG to PNG and appending to document with proper sizing

Tags: javascript, html, svg, html2canvas, sveltekit

Okay, so here's a pretty niche question.
I'm using html2canvas to create a screenshot(thumbnail) of a dom element. From there I am creating an image element and appending to that element an SVG which is contained within the parent element as a child.
When I create this screenshot the images show up, but they're breaking out of their bounds.
My question is if there is a way to make my image elements adhere to their bound during this screenshot process.
I am using SvelteKit for my client, if that helps anything at all.

Here is the function which is creating the screenshot:

```js
export const screenshotCanvas = async (element: string): Promise<File | null> => {
    const el: HTMLElement | null = document.querySelector(element);
    const svgAssets = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    
    if (el) {
        const canvas = await html2canvas(el, {
            allowTaint: true,
            useCORS: true,
            logging: true,
            imageTimeout: 0,
            proxy: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
            onclone: (doc) => {
                svgAssets.forEach((asset) => {
                    console.log('assets', asset, asset.width, asset.height)
                    const img = doc.createElement('img');
                    img.src = asset.src;
                    img.width = asset.width;
                    img.height = asset.height;
                    doc.body.appendChild(img);
                });
            }
        });

        const blob = await new Promise((resolve) => canvas.toBlob(resolve));
        // TODO handle error if blob is null somehow
        const file = new File([blob], 'thumbnail.webp', { type: 'image/webp' });
        return file;
    }
    return null;
};
```

Here is the parent element, which is what is being passed into the screenshotCanvas element:

```js
<div id="canvas" style="background: {background}">
        {#if info.elements}
            {#each info.elements as element}
                <ImgElement {element} />
            {/each}
        {/if}
        {#if $howToIsOpen}
            <HowToModal />
        {/if}
    </div>
```

And here is the child element, which can be any number of elements within the canvas:

```js
<div
    class="canvas-element"
    style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; position: absolute; top: {top +
        '%'}; left: {left + '%'}; z-index: {zIndex}; height: {height + '%'};"
>
    {#if loading}
        <Loading />
    {/if}
    {#if image && !loading}
        <img
            src={image.publicUrl}
            alt={element.elementName}
            on:mousedown={startMoving}
            draggable="false"
            on:contextmenu={(e) => {
                contextMenu(e);
                isOpen = true;
            }}
        />
    {/if}
</div>
```

In this image, the large image is the elements which I am creating a thumbnail of.
The boxes below are the 'pages' of the story and as you can see, the SVG images aren't adhering to the bounds of the parent div of the image element.
[image]

The public URL being used as the source is a reference to an SVG assets stored in my supabase storage.

Comment: Your screenshot function asks for `asset.width` and `.height`, but in your child element, no explicit sizes are set.  Where is that information supposed to come from?

Comment: @ccprog
My apologies, the CSS has a property of height 100%. Since the SVG asset is set to responsive, the height is the only thing that needs to be set.

Comment: I am still struggling to understand the purpose of the `onclone` callback. As far as I can see, it adds the images **after** your `#canvas` parent element, so they would show up _outside_ of what you are taking a screenshot of. The images shown _inside_ are what html2canvas pulls in itself, and if those have wrong dimensions, wouldn't you need to correct those? As in: `doc.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => { img.width = asset.width; img.height = asset.height; })`

Comment: So ``html2canvas`` creates the canvas in memory? Looks like your canvas is where it goes wrong, thus your IMG is wrong. Personally I would skip all the mumbo jumbo and do it Vanilla JS, shouldn't be any more code than you have now.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman
How would you recommend going about this?

Comment: Use Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=svg+to+canvas+to+png